# Deleting feature based on attribute using arcpy.da.Walk on file geodatabase

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, delete, walk

I'm very new to scripting and am having trouble figuring out how to use `da.Walk` to delete features based on attributes for my entire geodatabase. I got the script below to work on an individual feature class but haven't had any luck altering it to work on the whole geodatabase. I'm getting the following error:

RuntimeError: 'in_table' is not a table or a featureclass

```
 import arcpy
 arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Documents\Test.gdb'
 fc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
 for files in arcpy.da.Walk(fc):
      for file in files:
           cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["Zel"])
           for row in cursor:
                if row[0] != "AND":
                     cursor.deleteRow()
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Have you reviewed our [self-assembling FAQ on arcpy.da.Walk](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/walk?tab=Frequent)?

Comment: You need to cycle through each of the feature classes in the geodatabase. Use "arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()" and then use the list to cycle through each feature class. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfeatureclasses.htm

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've reviewed existing solutions and am still stuck. My script has been updated to include my attempt at using arcpy.da.Walk.

Comment: Wrong indentation to process the cursor. All you do is leave open write locks.  Use the `with` directive as in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code sample, your logic is a bit messed up. I assume that's because you're trying to update your code from `ListFeatureClasses` to making use of `da.Walk`.
Your code, right now, is passing the list `fc` from `ListFeatureClasses` into the cursor and not using walk.

If all you want to do is iterate over all the feature classes in your defined workspace, you can drop the `walk` part and use `ListFeatureClasses`. It could do everything you need. If you have multiple workspaces or different types of classes (ie feature classes and tables), then the `da.walk` might be a better approach (and drop `ListFeatureClasses`)

So either use  `ListFeatureClasses`:

```
 import arcpy
 arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Documents\Test.gdb'
 fc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
 for f in fc:
    cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(f, ["Zel"])
       for row in cursor:
          if row[0] != "AND":
             cursor.deleteRow()
```

or change it around to `da.Walk` (note that you've hard coded your cursor to look for the field **Zel**, you'll need to be sure that field exists in every featureclass the code encounters):

```
import arcpy
import os

workspace =  r'C:\Documents\Test.gdb'
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace)

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    for filename in filenames:
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(os.path.join(dirpath, filename), ["Zel"]) as cursor:
           for row in cursor:
              if row[0] != "AND":
                 cursor.deleteRow()
```